# Why this image can't be loaded whenever online Javascript code editor/interpreter is used?

Tags: javascript, flutter, image

It seems it has to do something with AmazonAWS, perhaps those services use it.
I tried to load [this image](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/162056main_PIA08329.jpg) in UI using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/) (Flutter mode). There are always exceptions or error when trying to render that image.

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Web Images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body:  Image(
  image: NetworkImage('https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/162056main_PIA08329.jpg'),
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: @user18309290 it works in ReactNative, forgot to import Image. But not clear, what with Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanvasKit` renderer needs access to image data, but the image is not available in other domains.

See [Cross-origin images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/web-images#cross-origin-images) for details.

Comment: But why it is available if use HtmlElementView?